# Printing an HTML Output in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've been creating a program with a variety of uses. I call it the Electronic Database with Direct Yield (EDDY). One thing that I have been having the most trouble with is EDDY's google search capabilities. EDDY will ask the user to give an input. EDDY will then edit the input slightly by replacing any spaces (' ') with plus signs ('+'), then go to the resulting url (without opening a browser). It then copies the html from the webpage and is SUPPOSED to give the results and descriptions of the site, and to specify, without the HTML code.

This is what I have so far.

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


    

def cleanup(url):
    

    html_content = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
    length = len(soup.prettify()) - 1
    print(soup.prettify()[16800:length])
    
    print(soup.title.text)

    print(soup.body.text)
    
    
def eddysearch():
    
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome.exe'}
    reg_url = "http://www.google.com/search?q="
    print("Ready for query")
    query = input()
    if(query != "quit"):
        print("Searching for keyword: " + query)
        print("Please wait...")
        search = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)
        url = reg_url + search
        req = Request(url=url, headers=headers)
        html = urlopen(req).read()
    
        cleanup(url)

        eddysearch()

    
eddysearch()
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for?

Answer (score -1):

hIf you dont want to use an SSL certificate, you can do `.read()`

```py
# Python 2.7.x
import urllib
url = "http://stackoverflow.com"
f = urllib.urlopen(url)
print f.read()
```

```py
#Python 3.x

import urllib.request
url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(f.read())
```